# How to extract the text from a sql column

Tags: sql

I have a pattern in a column in sql table ..

> IF PAIRING IS NOT SUCCESSFUL, 
>       REPEAT THE PAIRING PROCESS. 
>       IF PAIRING IS STILL NOT SUCCESSFUL, REPLACE THE MOTOR.

I wish to extract the text "PAIRING IS STILL NOT SUCCESSFUL". The text after second if ". IF" before "," and also the text after the comma has to be either REPLACE or REPAIR or TEST..

I tried this way..

> SUBSTRING( TextName,(PATINDEX('%. IF%,%', TextName) + 9), 20)

The third part of the substring is currently hardcoded, but how to genarlize the query.

Thanks
Ramm

Answer (score 3):

```
-- Test Data
DECLARE @T TABLE(
    TextName NVARCHAR(4000)
)

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 'IF PAIRING IS NOT SUCCESSFUL, REPEAT THE PAIRING PROCESS. IF PAIRING IS STILL NOT SUCCESSFUL, REPLACE THE MOTOR.'

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 'IF NOT WITHIN THE SPECIFIED RANGE, TEST THE MOTOR FOR A SV, SG, OR AN OHR. IF THE CIRCUIT TESTS NORMAL, REPLACE THE MOTOR.'


-- Example Query

SELECT SUBSTRING(TextName, PosPeriod, PosComma - PosPeriod) 'String1'
FROM
(
    SELECT TextName,
        CHARINDEX('.', TextName) + 5 'PosPeriod', -- 5 is to skip over the '. IF '        
        CHARINDEX(',', TextName, CHARINDEX('.', TEXTName)+1 ) 'PosComma'
    FROM @T
) TEMPTABLE
```

Comment: If the text is little bit different, like "IF NOT WITHIN THE SPECIFIED RANGE, TEST THE MOTOR FOR A SV, SG, OR AN OHR. IF THE CIRCUIT TESTS NORMAL, REPLACE THE MOTOR.".. ??

Comment: I updated the answer. You now search for the comma after the first period.

Comment: The results of the above query are: PAIRING IS STILL NOT SUCCESSFUL
and THE CIRCUIT TESTS NORMAL

Comment: Thanks a lot Kells.. I modified your query a little bit, REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(TextName), PATINDEX('% ,%', REVERSE(TextName)) +2, PATINDEX('% .%', REVERSE(TextName)) - PATINDEX('% ,%', REVERSE(TextName)) - 5) ). For few wordings like "abcd 1.0 sdfdjfl, dsf. If the dsfkjdskf, replace dsfds". In this case, the charindex fetches out the "." in 1.0.. so I used the reverse function, so that extraction can be bit simple